# Report Viewer Tool Date Parameter Is Not Valid For Its Type

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services

I have a question but i am not sure what is the problem or the cause. Hope you guys can help me on this.

I am using "Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms" to display my SSRS report.

But Currently when i pass the parameter needed as "24/04/2019" and click "View Report" I will get this error.

[image]

If the date parameter is passsed as "04/24/2019" then it will show the report.

I try to open the report by using browser and the date send is as "04/24/2019" thus it will not throw error.

And what makes it more weird, when i try to run on some of my friend's machine it is ok. I have check the region of our machine and it is the same("United States")

Here is my code

```
            reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
            ServerReport serverReport = reportViewer1.ServerReport;
            System.Net.ICredentials credentials = new NetworkCredential(ssrsViewerUserName, ssrsViewerPassword, Environment.UserDomainName);
            ReportServerCredentials rsCredentials = serverReport.ReportServerCredentials;
            rsCredentials.NetworkCredentials = credentials;
            serverReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(ssrsServerPath);
            serverReport.ReportPath = reportPath;
            reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Currently only when i use report viewer tool in my machine it will throw error. Any thoughts on this? Is there a way for me to make my report viewer tool to follow date format the same as my browser? Which is MM/DD/YYYY

**UPDATE**
This is my temporary solution. As it is not happening to all machines, so what i did is just changing the format of the date by going to Control Panel > Clock & Region > Change date, time, or number format and then go to Format Tab and change the value to United States.

Comment: `24/04/2019` is not a valid date if `CultureInfo` is `InvariantCulture` or a culture (like `en-US`)  which has different DateTime formats (i.e., `MM/dd/yyyy`).

Comment: @Jimi Hai Jimi. Thanks for the reply. Is there a way that i can make sure my report viewer tool to follow time format just like my browser? Which is MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: Well, don't feed dates formatted like this: `24/04/2019` (`dd/MM/yyyy`). You have the `InvariantCulture` format and the more general `yyyy/MM/dd`. Try parse the string with `DateTime.TryParseExact` to verify whether the string is accepted in the current culture format. If you pass a DateTime to a tool, use the `InvariantCulture` format.

Comment: @Jimi i did not pass the parameter from the code. I just display the report in report viewer tool and set the parameter there